# Power from Pi 3 to 7" display

Tags: hardware, power, power-supply

Does the 3v3 carried in the FFC cable at the display header of the Pi 3 B+ supply power to the 7" touch display?  Or do I need to supply power at J1.1 and .5?  If so this power can be pulled from the Pi 3 board on the I/O expansion header??

Comment: Which display, do you have a link?

Comment: https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156/l/raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display

Comment: Prompted by joan about the specific display lead me to the info I was looking for.  Thanks Joan!

Answer (score 5):

There's two ways to power it.

1. With a USB-A to microUSB cable. Plug that into the USB-A socket on your screen, plug the microUSB into your RPi. Connect your wall-wart power supply to the microUSB on the screen.
2. With two dupont wires, one on pin#2 or pin#4 (connected the the 5V pin on the display) the other on pin#6 (or any other GND pin connected to the GND pin on the display). DO NOT connect those middle two pins (grey and white wires in this photo).

[image: Screen wiring connections]